# Segmentation fault without altering my program

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I was trying to write a program that calculates prime numbers using threads and the program was working but not giving the desired results (it was telling all numbers were prime numbers). Today I tried to run the program again and I'm getting a segmentation fault even though I didn't alter my program. I tried using gdb to find when it was happening and I think it's happening on the pthread_join function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int n_threads; // number of threads
int* numbers; // array of numbers
int elements_per_thread;

int isPrime(int n){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        if(n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void * threadPrime(void * arg){
    int* idxp = (int*)arg;
    int idx = *idxp;
    int start = idx* elements_per_thread;
    int finish = (idx+1)*elements_per_thread-1;
    int i;
        for(i=start; i<finish; i++)
            if(!isPrime(i))
                numbers[i]=0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("usage: %s largest_number number_threads\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  int largest_number = atoi(argv[1]); // value of the largest number to test for primality
  int n_numbers = largest_number-1; // number of numbers to test
  n_threads = atoi(argv[2]);

  // create and fill vector of numbers to test  
  numbers = (int *)malloc(n_numbers*sizeof(int)) ;  // allocate a vector for n_numbers integers

  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= largest_number; i++) 
    numbers[i-2] = i;

  int* id = (int *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(int));
  // compute primes

 pthread_t* thid = (pthread_t *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(int));
 for(i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
    id[i] = i;
    if(pthread_create(&thid[i],NULL,threadPrime,(void*)(id+i)) != 0){
       printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }
 }

 for(i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
    if(pthread_join(thid[i],NULL) != 0){
        printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }
 }

  // print result 
   printf("Primes:");
  int n_primes = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n_numbers; i++) 
     if (numbers[i]) {
        n_primes++;
        printf (" %d", numbers[i]);
     }
  printf("\nTotal: %d primes\n", n_primes);

  return 0;         
}
```

Problem solved. Correct code below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int n_threads; // number of threads
int* numbers; // array of numbers
int elements_per_thread;

int isPrime(int n){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=2; i < n; i++)
        if(n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void * threadPrime(void * arg){
    int* idxp = (int*) arg;
    int idx = *idxp;
    int start = idx*elements_per_thread;
    int finish = (idx+1)*elements_per_thread;
    int i;
        for(i=start; i<=finish; i++)
            if(!isPrime(numbers[i]))
                numbers[i]=0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 if (argc != 3) {
    printf("usage: %s largest_number number_threads\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  int largest_number = atoi(argv[1]); // value of the largest number to test for primality
  int n_numbers = largest_number-1; // number of numbers to test
  n_threads = atoi(argv[2]);

  // create and fill vector of numbers to test  
  numbers = (int *)malloc(n_numbers*sizeof(int)) ;  // allocate a vector for n_numbers integers

  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= largest_number; i++) 
    numbers[i-2] = i;

  int* id;
  id = (int *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(int));

  // compute primeselements_per_thread = n_numbers/n_threads;

  elements_per_thread = (n_numbers/n_threads)+1;

 pthread_t* thid = malloc(n_threads*sizeof(*thid));

 for(i=0;i<n_threads;i++){
    id[i] = i;
    if(pthread_create(&thid[i],NULL,threadPrime,(void*)(id+i)) != 0){
        printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }
 }

 for(i=0;i<n_threads;i++){  
    if(pthread_join(thid[i],NULL) != 0){
        printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }
 }

  // print result 
  printf("Primes:");
  int n_primes = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n_numbers; i++) 
     if (numbers[i]) {
        n_primes++;
        printf (" %d", numbers[i]);
     }
  printf("\nTotal: %d primes\n", n_primes);

  return 0;         
}
```

Comment: `pthread_t* thid = (pthread_t *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(int));` --> `pthread_t* thid = (pthread_t *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));`

Comment: Where's `elements_per_thread` initialized?

Comment: I should probably mention that segmentation faults may or may not happen on any given run of the problem in C, because what your code actually has is **undefined behavior**, and a segfault is just one possible of those UBs. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33047453/472647) for more info in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

1) The starting index for the loop should  be 2. Otherwise, you are going to have divide by zero error here:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++) // should be i=2
   if(n%i == 0)
        return 0;
```

2) `elements_per_thread` is not set at all. So it's going to be 0 (since it's a global variable) and the loops in thread function will never be called. Set it in main():

```
elements_per_thread = n_numbers/n_threads;
```

3) When you call `isPrime()` you are passing `i`. But you really wanted to pass `numbers[i]`. You also want to include the `finish` in the primality test. So it should be

```
    for(i=start; i<=finish; i++)
        if(!isPrime(numbers[i]))
            numbers[i]=0;
```

4) The allocation for thread array is wrong. It should be

```
pthread_t* thid = malloc(n_threads * sizeof *thid);
```

There are more efficient ways to test primes (e.g. you only need to check upto n/2 to see if it's prime). But once you fix the above issues, you'll have a working code and think about improving it later.

Comment: Actually, up to sqrt(n).

Comment: You are right. Haven't done it a while :) OP can read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for greater details.

Comment: I was able to fix my code thanks to you. Thank you very much!
I now have problem with finding the prime numbers. When I don't use exactly 3 threads my output says that 98, 99 and 100 are all prime numbers and they aren't. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening but I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: @endorphin2009 That's because of integer division in C. For example, if you input 100 and 5 then the range is 0 to 99. But 99/5 is 19. You need to re-write the logic if the numbers/threads is not evenly divisible.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!! I had no idea  that "99/5 is 19" in C. I can't thank you enough I've been looking at this program for so long. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate the right amount of memory for `thid`. This is the main reason for your segmentation fault.

```
pthread_t* thid = (pthread_t *)malloc(n_threads*sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
pthread_t* thid = malloc(n_threads*sizeof(p_thread));
```

(you don't need to cast `malloc` in C)

This is why I don't usually use an explicit type as the operand of `sizeof`, and instead just use the variable name so that the compiler can deduce the type itself.

```
pthread_t* thid = malloc(n_threads*sizeof(*thid));
```