# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I delete pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from a linked list, and encountered a problem, which is probably obvious and straightforward but I haven't used `C++` in many years and I couldn't find out what I am doing wrong by reading similar questions on SO.

Below is parts of my code. I removed irrelevant parts (eg. constructors, other methods, etc).

```
template<class T>
class Node {
  Node() : data(NULL), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
  explicit Node(T d) : data(d), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
  explicit Node(T d, Node<T> *nxt, Node<T> *prv) : data(d), next(nxt),    prev(prv) {}
  ~Node() { delete next; delete prev; }

  T data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList {
  LinkedList() : head(NULL) {}
  explicit LinkedList(Node<T> *head_node) : head(head_node) {}
  LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &copy_list);
  ~LinkedList(); //didn't implement this but I guess delete head is all?

  Node<T>* head;
};


template<class T>
LinkedList<T> RemoveDuplicates(const LinkedList<T> &linked_list) {
  //my = overload creates a whole new list with the same data as the original one
  LinkedList<T> result = linked_list; 

  Node<T> *cur = result.head;
  Node<T> *prev = NULL;

  while (cur) {
    if (...) { //duplicate found  
      Node<T> *temp = cur;
      prev->next = cur->next;
      cur = cur->next;
      cur->prev = prev;
      free(temp); //Here is my problem!!!
    }
    else {
      prev = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

So first, I did `delete temp` and I got `Segmentation fault`. I then realized you only `delete` what you `new`. Fair enough, but I am `new`ing each `Node` when building the whole list in `main`:

```
Node<char> *h = new Node<char>('H'); //I have a constructor to handle this
Node<char> *e = new Node<char>('E');
Node<char> *l1 = new Node<char>('L');
Node<char> *l2 = new Node<char>('L');
Node<char> *o = new Node<char>('O');

h->next = e;
h->prev = NULL;

e->next = l1;
e->prev = h;

//and so on
```

So why I am not allowed to `delete` something that was `new`ed somewhere else? Is it because it was `new`ed outside the current scope?

Second, `free`ing the space works fine, but obviously not the right thing to do because I didn't `malloc` but `new`ed!

What am I doing wrong? How to properly kill that removed node?

Edit1: Made it more descriptive according to replies to my post
Edit2: Rule of 3 methods added

Comment: [Possibly helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33047452/472647)

Comment: `~Node() { delete next; delete prev; }` will kill the nodes around it. For example, you remove Node Y from between Nodes X and Z, linking X and Z. You then `delete Y` to get it's resources back. Y's destructor will then destroy X and Z. X and Z's destructors will destroy all that they touch, including X and Z which are in the process of being destroyed. This is what we used to call a very bad scene. I'd rethink the destructor logic if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an addendum to other answers which correctly identify and solve the OP's immediate problem. A quick walk-though is required to explain what will happen next.

```
  Node<T> *temp = cur;
  prev->next = cur->next;
  cur = cur->next;
  cur->prev = prev;
```

At this point temp has not been cleared so next and prev still point to the two nodes that used to surround cur and are now linked together. This will cause serious problems if not for:

```
  free(temp); //Here is my problem!!!
```

`free` fails because the value pointed to by temp was allocated by new. NathanOliver's answer has this covered, but lurking beneath is what will happen with

```
delete temp;
```

This will invoke the destructor to clean up like a good little object. Unfortunately the `Node` destructor looks like this:

```
~Node() { delete next; delete prev; }
```

`temp->next` still points to a live node. So does `temp->prev`.

Next and prev get `delete`d. Which calls their destructors, `delete`ing the two nodes they touch, and invokes a deathstorm that will destroy all of the Nodes in the list.

If the double-deletes don't kill the program first. Each linked node will try to `delete` the node that just `deleted` them. Not good.

Odds are pretty good that the `Node` destructor should just look after itself and leave the destruction of the other `Node`s to the `LinkedList` class.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `free()` if you allocated memory with `new`

You can use `malloc()` with `free()` or `new` with `delete`.  You also should not use `malloc()` and `free()` with objects as they do not call the objects constructor  and destructor unlike `new` and `delete`

So since you allocated the nodes with `new` we can change

```
free(temp); //Here is my problem!!!
```

to

```
delete temp;
```

Comment: I get `Segmentation fault' when I do `delete temp`

Comment: then you have an issue somewhere in the code.  Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: @Yalda [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) problems most probably.

Comment: Thanks @πάντα ῥεῖ! I thought there might be something obviously wrong in my code, and seems that's not the case.

Comment: It is. Deleting my comment as you've covered the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

In this case having the code of the constructor and also of destructor is very important.

By default you should use "new" in constructor and "delete" in destructor. To be more specific, is very important to allocate all the resources you need in constructor and deallocate in destructor, this way you ensure you don't have any memory leaks.

```
free(temp);//You don't need this, also you don't need delete.
```

Please post your constructor and your destructor code.

L.E:

I think you should do something like this:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
  private:
    struct Node {
        T m_data;
        Node *m_next;
        Node *m_prev;
    };
    Node* m_first;
    Node* m_last;
    int m_count;
  public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    T GetFirst();
    T GetLast();
    void AddNode(T node);
    void RemoveAt(int index);
    T GetAt(int index);
    int Count();
};

//constructor
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    m_count = -1;//-1 == "The list is empty!
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddNode(T data){
    Node* temp = new Node; //new is called only here -> delete is called in destructor or in RemoveAt
    temp->m_data = data;
    if (m_count > -1){//If the list contains one or more items
        temp->m_next = m_first;
        temp->m_prev = m_last;
        m_last->m_next = temp;
        m_last = temp;
        m_count++;
    }
    else if (m_count == -1)
    {//If no items are present in the list
        m_first = temp;
        m_first->m_next = temp;
        m_first->m_prev = temp;
        m_last = temp;
        m_last->m_next = temp;
        m_last->m_prev = temp;
        m_count = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveAt(int index){
    if (index <= m_count)//verify this request is valid
    {
        Node* temp = m_last;
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i){
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        temp->m_prev->m_next = temp->m_next;
        temp->m_next->m_prev = temp->m_prev;
        delete temp;
        m_count--;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::GetAt(int index)
{
    Node* temp = m_first;
    if (index <= m_count && index > -1){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < index){
            temp = temp->m_next;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return temp->m_data;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::GetFirst() {
    return m_first->data;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::GetLast(){
    return m_last->data;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::Count(){
    return m_count;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
   while(m_count > -1){
        Node* temp = m_first;
        m_first = temp->m_next;
        delete temp;//delete in destructor
        m_count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just added those! But there is some space in memory nobody needs any more (or pointing to). How can I not need to delete it?

Comment: I see your problem, I'm preparing some sample code for you.

Comment: I've added some code about how I think it should be done.

Comment: Thanks @Heto, your piece of code has a lot to learn from and I see my piece of code has many bugs :)

Answer (score 2):

> So why I am not allowed to delete something that was newed somewhere
>   else? Is it because it was newed outside the current scope?

You're allowed to `delete` things `new`ed elsewhere. This is not a problem as long as you're pointing to a valid address. The seg-fault shows up when you then try to use one of the pointers that was pointing to the now-`delete`ed address.

> Second, freeing the space works fine, but I feel that's like cheating!

You should only use `free` when you've used `malloc` and `delete` when you've used `new`. You should *never* mix them up. Also, after you `delete`, get into the habit of assigning `NULL` to the pointer variable.

> Because I may need things to be done on my Node's destructor.

The class encapsulating the data should also do its own memory management internally. For example, the `LinkedList` should manage the memory of the nodes.

This means that, if you have something similar to `LinkedList<T>::add(Node<T> *data)`, you should instead consider something like `LinkedList<T>::add(T data)`; then the list class itself takes care of handling the nodes.

Otherwise, you run the risk of sending a `new`ed node into the list, then the list `delete`s it internally at some point, but somewhere else, the list's client still holds a reference to a now-invalid node. When the client tries to use it, bam!: seg-fault again.

> What am I doing wrong? How to properly kill that removed node?

Besides mixing the `new`s with `free`s, the segfault is likely being triggered by an invalid memory access, so you should find the pointer that is no longer pointing to valid (i.e. un`deleted`) memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers stating that `new/delete` and `malloc()/free()` should always be paired so, but I feel that it should be said *why* exactly.

As in your initializations,

```
Node<char> *h = new Node<char>('H');
```

the `new` keyword returns a fully typed object object pointer, defined in the statement itself, while `malloc()` simply allocates a given memory space without assigning a type, and so returns a `void*`. Additionally, `new/delete` deal with memory from the Free Store while `malloc()/free()` allocate/free memory on the Heap, although some compilers might implement `new/free` in terms of `malloc()/free` in some instances.

Also of some importance is that `new` and `delete` call the constructor and destructor respectively, while `malloc()` and `free()` simply allocate and deallocate heap memory, with no regard for the state of the memory itself.