# C - Print job schedule using pthreads, but qPointer is null instead of pointing to front of queue

Tags: c, struct, queue, pthreads, null-pointer

I am trying to use C to print a job schedule using pthreads. But in nextTaskInQueue(), qPointer does not cause a segmentation fault, but it is NULL instead of pointing to front of node queue. When you run the executable, be sure to add 2 on the end as the command line argument. Since my code requires input, type the following for the input: Jim (tab) A (tab) 2 (tab) 5 (enter) Mary (tab) B (tab) 2 (tab) 3 (enter) Sue (tab) A (tab) 5 (tab) 5 (enter) Mary (tab) C (tab) 6 (tab) 4 (enter). Here is my source code below.

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char user[5];
    char process;
    int arrival;
    int duration;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct Q
{
    node *R,*F;
}Q;

struct display
{
    char user[5];
    int timeLastCalculated;
    struct display *next;
} *frontDisplay, *tempDisplay, *rearDisplay;

pthread_mutex_t m1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t m2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
Q q;

void initialise(Q *);
int empty(Q *);
void enqueue(Q *, char[5], char, int, int);
void* jobDisplay();
struct node* nextTaskInQueue();
void addToSummary(char[], int);
void summaryDisplay();

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    //sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    int n;
    if( argc == 2 )
    {
        if ( strcmp(argv[1],"2") == 0 )
        {
            n = atoi(argv[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The argument supplied is not 2.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if( argc > 2 )
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("One argument expected.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char user[5], process;
    int arrivalInput, durationInput;

    initialise(&q);
    printf("\n\tUser\tProcess\tArrival\tDuration\n");

    int i = 1;
    while ( i < 5 )
    {
        printf("\t");
        if ( scanf("%s\t%c\t%d\t%d", user, &process, &arrivalInput, &durationInput) < 4 )
        {
            printf("\nThe arguments supplied are incorrect. Try again.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        enqueue(&q, user, process, arrivalInput, durationInput);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nThis would result in:\n\tTime\tJob\n\t");

    pthread_t threadID[n];
    i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        pthread_create(&(threadID[i]),NULL,&jobDisplay,NULL);
    }
    pthread_join(threadID[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(threadID[1],NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2);
    summaryDisplay();
    return 0;
}

void initialise(Q *qPointer)
{
    qPointer->R=NULL;
    qPointer->F=NULL;
    rearDisplay=NULL;
    tempDisplay=NULL;
    frontDisplay=NULL;
}

void enqueue(Q *qPointer, char user[5], char process, int arrivalE, int durationE)
{
    node *eP;
    eP=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    strcpy(eP->user, user);
    eP->process=process;
    eP->arrival=arrivalE;
    eP->duration=durationE;

    eP->next=NULL;
    if ( empty(qPointer) )
    {
        qPointer->R=eP;
        qPointer->F=eP;
    }
    else
    {
        (qPointer->R)->next=eP;
        qPointer->R=eP;
    }
}

void* jobDisplay()
{
    int myTime = 0;
    struct node* placeholder = NULL;
    placeholder = nextTaskInQueue();
    while ( placeholder != NULL )
    {
        if ( myTime < placeholder->arrival )
        {
            sleep( placeholder->arrival - myTime );
            myTime = placeholder->arrival;
        }
        printf("%d\t%c\n", myTime, placeholder->process);
        sleep(placeholder->duration);
        myTime += placeholder->duration;
        addToSummary(placeholder->user, myTime);
        placeholder = nextTaskInQueue();
    }
    printf("%d\tCPU %d IDLE\n", myTime, pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

struct node* nextTaskInQueue()
{
    struct node* placeholder = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
    struct Q* qPointer=(struct Q *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct Q));
    if ( qPointer->F != NULL )
    {
        placeholder = qPointer->F;
        qPointer->F = placeholder->next;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);

    return placeholder;
}

void addToSummary(char name[], int timeLeft)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);

    if ( rearDisplay == NULL )
    {
        rearDisplay = (struct display *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct display));
        rearDisplay->next = NULL;
        strcpy(rearDisplay->user, name);
        rearDisplay->timeLastCalculated = timeLeft;
        frontDisplay = rearDisplay;
    }
    else
    {
        tempDisplay = frontDisplay;
        while ( tempDisplay != NULL )
        {
            if ( strcmp(tempDisplay->user, name) == 0 )
            {
                tempDisplay->timeLastCalculated = timeLeft;
                break;
            }
            tempDisplay = tempDisplay->next;
        }
        if ( tempDisplay == NULL )
        {
            tempDisplay = (struct display *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct display));
            rearDisplay->next = tempDisplay;
            strcpy(tempDisplay->user, name);
            tempDisplay->timeLastCalculated = timeLeft;
            tempDisplay->next = NULL;
            rearDisplay = tempDisplay;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
}

void summaryDisplay()
{
    printf("\nSummary\n");

    while ( frontDisplay != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", frontDisplay->user, frontDisplay->timeLastCalculated);
        tempDisplay = frontDisplay->next;
        free(frontDisplay);
        frontDisplay = tempDisplay;
    }
}

int empty(Q *qPointer)
{
    if ( qPointer->R==NULL )
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the dumped core? It should be fairly obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: I found where the segmentation fault was occurring. It is in nextTaskInQueue(). "Q* qPointer;" is now "struct Q* qPointer=(struct Q *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct Q));" and that stops the segmentation fault from happening again. However, it creates a new problem where the qPointer is now null instead of pointing to the front of the node queue. Any ideas on a potential solution to that?

Comment: @user2236932 If there is a new problem, please ask a new question.