# C -Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why this code is showing Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int*,int*);

int main(){
    int x=5,y=10;
    swap(&x,&y);
    printf("%d%d",x,y);
    return 1;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int *temp;
    *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int *temp;` is the problem. It is not pointing to any memory that you own. The behaviour on dereferencing `temp` is undefined.

Use `int temp;` instead, (preferably `int temp = *a;` since then `temp` is never in an uninitialised state) and `temp` rather than `*temp` in the assignments.

(By the way, `0` is conventionally the return value from `main` that indicates success.)

Answer (score 2):

In swap() function you declare a pointer (int *temp;) and just after you dereference it using (*temp = ...). At initialization temp contains nothing (well, probably 0, but whatever), and '*temp' means "the integer that is at address contained in temp".

Here you want to manipulated an int:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int temp;
  temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`int *temp;`
```

This statement just creates a pointer to a integer. So, before

```
*temp = *a;
```

You need to allocate a memory to which temp will point. otherwise temp will have some junk value that will make it a pointer to a random location. So if you are using `int *temp` then allocate memory before using or you can use int variable `int temp;`