# Segmentation fault 11 on strcpy()

Tags: segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to copy "init" into my string array, and I can't figure out why. If I comment out the `strcpy()` line, I don't get a segmentation fault and `init` prints fine.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char *init = readToken(fp);
    printf("%s",init);      
    char **words =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2); 
    strcat(*words,init);
```

PS: `readToken` is an `fscanf`.

Comment: Can you please post readToken(..) as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate an array of `char *`s:

```
char **words =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
```

These `char *`s point to *nothing* in particular. They might be NULL, they might be pointing into the stack, who knows. They're uninitialized and undefined.

```
strcat(*words,init);
```

Is like saying

```
strcat(words[0], init);
```

If `words[0]` already pointed to some sort of valid string, this would work. As it is, you're appending a string to some unknown point in memory.

```
strcpy(*words, init);
```

Just *writes* the string into that unknown point in memory, so that won't help.

You need to allocate space for your new string. The simplest way is through `strdup()`, which makes a copy of the passed in string. So:

```
*words = strdup(init);
```

will do fine, as would

```
words[0] = strdup(init);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char **words =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
```

Why are you using a double pointer?

Anyway, if you want to pass `*words` to `strcat` as destination, you have to allocate it, since the above line just allocates memory for `char **words`, but when you dereference it you have a pointer which points to an undefined area of the memory

Comment: What do you mean by allocate it? Is there a difference in allocating memory and allocating? or are you not talking about "*words"?

Comment: Also, I'm using a double pointer because it's an array of strings.