# Conditional checking on strlen(NULL) gives segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

I'm writing a function that contains the following loop. This segment reads from a text file that contains multiple lines of text, each of which contain a single word and the \r\n characters.

```
int strSize = 100;
char* sPtr = (char*)malloc(strSize*sizeof(char));
char* tPtr = (char*)malloc(strSize*sizeof(char)); 
FILE* fp = fopen("someTextFile.txt","r"); 

fgets(sPtr, strSize, fp); //Read in first line  

while(sPtr != NULL) {
   tPtr = strtok(sPtr, "\r\n"); //There's one word per line, which terminates with \r\n
   if( strlen(tPtr) > 0)
   {
     ... Do stuff
   }
   sPtr = fgets(sPtr, strSize, fp); //Read next line, if fgets() reaches EOF, then sPtr <= NULL
}
```

The problematic line is: `if( strlen(tPtr) > 0)`. If tPtr is NULL, then this line causes a seg. fault (strangely calling `strlen(tPtr)` doesn't give a seg fault).

Anyways, I thought this wouldn't be a problem since sPtr gets checked at the beginning of the while loop for the NULL-case. So evidently, after `strtok(sPtr, "\r\n")` operates on sPtr, for some non-NULL sPtr, you get NULL. But I don't see how this can happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: Figured it out: it read an empty string with \n, which when strtok() returned a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. Accessing a NULL pointer is officially **undefined behvaior**, meaning that anything and everything might happen. A segmentation fault is just one of those possible undefined behaviors.

A NULL pointer is also returned by `strtok` if the token you're searching for is not found, which is why you continue to get a segfault after checking for NULL in your code. [See the documentation.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)