# C++ - Getting segfault while creating a Linked List

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a simple linked list and a variable t oread through it. However, I'm gettin a segfault in a place I didn't think would get one. Here's my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    struct Node {
     string name;
     Node *next;
    };

    int main() {
     Node *one;
     one->name = "one";
     Node *two;
     two->name = "two";
     Node *three;
     three->name = "three";

     Node *reader = one;
     while (reader != NULL) {
      cout << reader->name << endl;
      reader = reader->next;
     }
    }
```

I added a few cout's around my code and realized that the segfault was happening after

```
    one->name = "one";
```

I'm not very experienced in C++, but I thought a segfault occurred when the stacks overflowed in memory. I don't see how the program should be running out of memory there.
I'd appreciate any help in finding out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You never allocated memory for your `node*` pointers.

Comment: Yer need less stars, fewer arrers and moar dots.

Comment: *I'm not very experienced in C++* -- Then it is a good idea to get a good C++ book and go through the examples, understanding everything as you go along.  You're making a fundamental mistake that no good book would have illustrated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 2):

You create a pointer to Node but you never create a Node-object.

Use

```
Node* one = new Node();
```

and don't forget `delete one;` at the end of your program.

Basically you have allocated memory for a pointer to `Node`, but the content is some random adress in memory. You need to actually create a Node-object and assign its adress to your pointer. If not, you are trying to dereference a random adress. (Compare it to writing `int i;` which will hold a random `int` if not initialized)