# Deadlock prevent

Tags: c, linux, deadlock

Need help how to prevent the deadlock for the code in blow i have written. or any suggestion i need to fix the code in order to get rid of deadlock?
also when i run in Linux i got a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int cnt;
int *bites;
int *old_bites;
sem_t *sticks;

void *roger(void *arg) {
    int rog = *(int*)arg;

    for(;;) {
        sem_wait(&(sticks[rog]));             // left
        sem_wait(&(sticks[(rog + 1) % cnt])); // right

        bites[rog]++;

        sem_post(&(sticks[(rog + 1) % cnt])); // right
        sem_post(&(sticks[rog]));             // left
}

pthread_exit(NULL);

return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i;
pthread_t *rogers;
int *pos;
cnt = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

rogers = (pthread_t *)calloc(cnt, sizeof(pthread_t));
pos = (int *)malloc(cnt * sizeof(int));
bites = (int *)calloc(cnt, sizeof(int));
old_bites = (int *)calloc(cnt, sizeof(int));
sticks = (sem_t *)calloc(cnt, sizeof(sem_t));

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    sem_init(&(sticks[i]), 0, 1);
}

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    pos[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&(rogers[i]), NULL, roger, (void *)&pos[i]);
}

for(;;) {
    bool dead = true;
    usleep(50000);
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        if(bites[i] != old_bites[i]) {
            dead = false;
        }
    }
    if(dead) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        printf("%8X", bites[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        old_bites[i] = bites[i];
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    pthread_join(rogers[i], NULL);  
}

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    sem_destroy(&(sticks[i]));
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: SegFault and deadlock?  Maybe go for the record and add a divide-by-zero?

Comment: OK, I'll bites.  Tell us what you have done so far to debug your app.  Which line raises the segfault?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Solutions

Comment: OP, you need to do some debugging. `gdb` and `valgrind` are incredibly helpful tools, especially where segmentation faults are concerned. More info about that on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults). Also, @user3386109, my brain immediately registered that link as "bistromath".

Comment: @JasonMc92 Ahh, that explains the title. OP meant airlock prevent.

Comment: @user3386109, LOL, let's not confuse the guy. (OP, ignore us, nerd jokes flying here.)

Answer (score 0):

yes I would expect this to deadlock.  I don't know what you're using for `cnt`, but let's pretend it's 1.  In this case, only 1 thread will get created.  This thread will `sem_wait(&(sticks[0]));`.  Then in the very next line it will `sem_wait(&(sticks[(0+1) % 1 == 0]));`.  Since the initial value of your semaphores are 1, you can't wait on the same semaphore twice without a `sem_post` first.  Thus, this thread will wait forever for a `sem_post` that it can't reach because it's `sem_wait`ing.

Now consider the case where `cnt > 1` (let's just say `cnt == 2` to make it simpler).  This will spawn thread0 and thread1 with 0 and 1 passed as arguments to their functions. This situation could happen:

- Thread0 executes `sem_wait(&(sticks[0]));`
- Context switch: thread1 executes `sem_wait(&(sticks[1]));`
- thread1 executes `sem_wait(&(sticks[(1+1) % 2 == 0]));  // this blocks because thread0 has already sem_wait'ed this semaphore to 0`
- Context switch: thread0 executes `sem_wait(&(sticks[(0+1) % 2 == 1]));  // this blocks because thread1 has already sem_wait'ed this semaphore to 0`

Now you have each thread waiting for a `sem_post` from the other before you can continue ==> deadlock.  I would expect this scenario to scale for increasing values of `cnt`, although the situations that would lead to deadlocks would become more complex.

Why are you using 2 semaphores to protect a single resource?  This theory sounds wrong to me.  You lose your atomicity with that approach (correct me if I'm wrong obviously).

Also, you have a race condition with your `bites` array.  The main thread isn't observing synchronization before it reads from it.  This may be related to the seg fault.

Comment: so i have fixed segFault, and is deadlock program will not end? and continuously print out output?

Comment: @littlerain From the code provided I expect your worker threads to eventually deadlock. All the printing happens in the main loop, which enters an infinite `for` loop and will exit if `dead` becomes true. This might happen sometimes, it might not. The `pthread_join` and `sem_destroy` loops will never be reached. I think your array of semaphores is a logical error. You should only have one. By using more than one semaphore in this way to protect a single resource (`bites` array) you remove the atomicity that thread synchronization is based on.