# Why is one seg faulting and the other not?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hi I have a program that needs to compare a string array to a predefined string but when I use the variable args[0] it works in my function strcmp as below

```
int gash_execute(char **args){
    int i;

    if(args[0] == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < gash_command_num(); i++){
        if(strcmp(args[0], functions[i]) == 0){
            return(*function_address[i])(args);     
        } 
    }
    return gash_launch(args);
}
```

However when trying to strcmp args[i] such as below I get a seg fault. Can anyone help me find a solution to this problem?

```
int gash_execute(char **args){
    int i;

    if(args[0] == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < gash_command_num(); i++){
        if(strcmp(args[i], functions[i]) == 0){
            return(*function_address[i])(args);     
        } 
    }
    return gash_launch(args);
}
```

args[] is an array of strings that were previously separated by spaces, this program is for a custom shell, so pretend in my shell command line I input "cat echo ls" args[0] would be "cat" and so on. However now I need to implement i/o redirection. So i need to check every element of args to check if they represent the symbols "<" ">" "|" and if one of them is we can take it from there

Comment: You are reading too far into the args array. Since you don't explain what any of your variables represent, it's hard to say much more.

Comment: What are `gash_command_num`, `functions`, `function_address`, and `gash_launch`? Better said: where's your Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you show the `gash_command_num()` source?

Comment: @t0mm13b args[0] does not point to anything. You cannot tell what it points to from this example.

Comment: @t0mm13b We definitely can't infer that from this example. Args could be anything, and "gash" is not a library that I can find published anywhere.

Comment: @t0mm13b You're assuming he's passing in argv from mains paramater list. You cannot infer that here.

Comment: sorry lads, I read that as main... my bad...

Comment: Is `gash_command_num()` number of `args` OR `functions` ?

Comment: args[] is an array of strings that were previously separated by spaces, this program is for a custom shell, so pretend in my shell command line I input "cat echo ls" args[0] would be "cat" and so on. However now I need to implement i/o redirection. So i need to check every element of args to check if they represent the symbols "<" ">" "|" and if one of them is we can take it from there.

Comment: It would be clearer if you passed in the number of valid arguments (that is, the number of valid pointers in `args`) as a second argument to `gash_execute`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all the code, or a report from a tool such as [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), I can't say for sure. But I can tell you that this loop is full of potential problems.

```
for(i = 0; i < gash_command_num(); i++){
    if(strcmp(args[i], functions[i]) == 0){
        return(*function_address[i])(args);     
    } 
}
```

It's iterating through three arrays (`args`, `functions`, and `function_address`) based on some function call which takes none of those as variables (`gash_command_num()`) which has an unknown relation to how many elements are actually in those arrays.

And it's using two global variables (`functions` and `function_addresses`) which could contain anything.

If all those things are related, I would suggest making that explicit... but I suspect they're not.  I suspect your loop logic is wrong. It's comparing `args[i]` with `functions[i]`. I suspect `gash_command_num()` is actually the size of `functions` and so the loop is walking off `args`.

***What I suspect you really want to do is to see if `args[0]` matches any function name in `functions` and then call the related function***.  If `args[0]` is `ls` then you want to check if there's a built in shell function for `ls` and call it with all the arguments.

Rather than searching a list over and over again, and having to manage two parallel lists, this would be much better served with a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The keys are the function names, the values are the function pointers.  C doesn't have a hash table built in, but there's plenty of libraries for that.  [Gnome Lib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) is a solid choice for this and many other basic functionality that C is missing.

Using a hash table, and eliminating the globals, your code reduces to this:

```
/* For encapsulation */
typedef int(*shell_function_t)(char **);

int gash_execute(char **args, GHashTable *shell_functions){
    int i;

    if(args[0] == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    shell_function_t func = g_hash_table_lookup(shell_functions, args[0]);
    if( func ) {
        return(*func)(args);
    }
    else {
        return gash_launch(args);
    }
}
```

Scanning for pipes is now a separate problem. For that you *do* want to loop through `args` looking for special characters. That is made much simpler if, when you create `args`, you ensure it ends with a null pointer.

```
for(int i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
    ...check if args[i] is special...
}
```