# location of segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am unable to locate the cause of the segmentation fault 
objective-to reverse a string using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void swap(char *ptr[], int c)
{
  int i;
  char  *r[40];    
  for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    *(r[c-i]) = *(ptr[i]);
  printf("%s",*r);
}

main()
{
  int i;
  char *ptr[20],str[40];

  printf("enter string:");
  gets(str);
  for(i=0; i<(strlen(str)); i++)
    ptr[i]=&(str[i]);
  swap(ptr,strlen(str));    
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are using an array of string pointers, but even so, `r[c-i]` should be `r[c-i-1]` if `c` is the array length. And then, you make the classic "howler" of swapping the characters *twice* instead of of stopping in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 3):

Problem lies here -

```
char  *r[40];    
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
  *(r[c-i])=*(ptr[i]);
```

Here you declare array of `char` pointers `r` and you dereference these uninitialized pointers which must have caused seg fault .