# Concatenation of string and int results in segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm trying to concatenate `hostname` with `pid` to create `id`.

```
char *generate_id(void) {
    int ret;
    char id[1048];
    char hostname[1024];
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    //hostname[1023] = '\0';

    if ((ret = gethostname(hostname,1024) < 0)) {
        perror("gethostname");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sprintf(id, "%s%d", pid);
    printf("hostname is %s\n", hostname);
    printf("The process id is %d\n", pid);
    printf("The unique id is %s", id);

    return id;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Updated code after reading some answers:

```
char *generate_id(void) {
    int ret;
    char hostname[1024];
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    //hostname[1023] = '\0';

    if ((ret = gethostname(hostname,1024) < 0)) {
        perror("gethostname");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%d", hostname, pid);
    char * id = malloc(size + 1);

    printf("hostname is %s\n", hostname);
    printf("The process id is %d\n", pid);
    printf("The unique id is %s\n", id);

    return id;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Working code:

```
char *generate_id(void) {
    int ret;
    char hostname[1024];
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    //hostname[1023] = '\0';

    if ((ret = gethostname(hostname,1024) < 0)) {
        perror("gethostname");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%d", hostname, pid);
    char * id = malloc(size + 1);
    sprintf(id, "%s%d", hostname, pid);
    printf("hostname is %s\n", hostname);
    printf("The process id is %d\n", pid);
    printf("The unique id is %s\n", id);

    return id;
}
```

Comment: sprintf `%s%d`, and then provide only `pid`? you have two formatting chars, so need to provide two values

Comment: Why do you have `%s%d` in sprintf shouldn't that just be `%d`

Comment: You should cast `pid_t pid` when supplying it as `int` argument. `sprintf(id, "%d", (int)pid);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue with your format string:

```
sprintf(id, "%s%d", pid);
```

Your format string has two formatters (`%s` for a string and `%d` for an `int`), yet you only pass an `pid_t`. You likely mean:

```
sprintf(id, "%s%d", hostname, pid);
```

or

```
sprintf(id, "%d", pid);
```

In your code, the `%s` interprets the `pid` as a pointer. Trying to dereference that to format the string causes the segmentation fault as it's an invalid pointer value.

## Issue with your memory management:

But then there's also **undefined behavior** in your code: you declare `id` to be a stack-allocated array but you're returning that array (which decays into a pointer here). This also is wrong and may lead to a crash later on.

You need to change `id` to a heap-allocated array like this:

```
char * id = malloc(1024);
```

The caller of your `generate_id` function then needs to `free` the memory when it's done.

It's probably a good idea to only allocate the space you need. You can use `snprintf` for that like this:

```
// Determine how much space the string needs.
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", pid);
// Allocate the required space plus NULL termination.
char * id = malloc(size + 1);
// Actually print the string.
sprintf(id, "%d", pid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the code in the question, when I try to print the unique id, its blank though.

Comment: That's because you only _allocate_ the space, but you're missing the actual call to `sprintf`. First, `snprintf` is called (notice the extra `n` in the name) in a special way (`NULL` and `0` as the first two arguments). This way you measure the size. Then you need to allocate the space with `malloc`, and _then_ you need to actually print into that space with `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are segfaulting but you have a few issues.

snprintf() is much safer and won't overrun the id[] buffer. sprintf could overrun the buffer

sprintf(id, "%s%d", pid) is bad as mentioned above.

return id is bad as it returns the pointer to a value on the stack. As soon as you return, the stack is no longer yours.

Comment: You must either allocate the memory (malloc) and have the caller free it, or use a static buffer that the caller knows needs to be copied or utilized before calling that routine again, or similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(id, "%s%d", pid);
```

You have two selectors %s and %d, but only one parameter (pid). You need to put in a string and an integer instead of just the integer.