# Segmentation fault in C when iterating through a string

Tags: c

I am very new to C and I am supposed to be creating the strtok function. Problem is, I keep getting a segmentation fault error in this code:

```
char *newstring = "testing, testing, tested."
while(*newstring != '\0' ){
    /*replace delimiters with nulls*/
    printf("STARTING ITERATION\n");
    if(*newstring ==','){
        *newstring='\0';
    }

    printf("newstring char in loop: %c\n", *newstring);
    /*printf("delimiters char in loop: %c\n", *delimiters);*/
    newstring++;
    printf("END OF ITERATION\n");
}
printf("OUT OF ITERATION");
```

Output is thus:

```
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: t
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: e
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: s
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: t
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop:
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: t
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: e
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: s
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: t
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop:
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: t
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: e
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: s
END OF ITERATION
STARTING ITERATION
newstring char in loop: .
END OF ITERATION
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, it looks like it gets all the way through to the end of the string and the very end of the loop, but doesn't actually make it OUT of the loop. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: you're modifying a string literal.. that's undefined behavior. Try `char newstring[] = "testing, testing, tested.";` instead.

Comment: A pointer is no array. Your code invokes undefined behaviour. You try to modify a _string literal_.

Comment: Do you know what a Literal String is?

Comment: @Michi: You mean _string literal_. A "literal string" might be some text from literature ;-) And one can be expected to search for a phrase one does not know: https://www.google.de/search?q=string+literal

Comment: @olaf Yes you right. :)))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to modify a string literal, which is not allowed in C. If you change `char *newstring = "testing, testing, tested."` to `char newstring[] = "testing, testing, tested."`, then you are modifying the contents of the array.

Comment: In C++ it would not compile.

Comment: Thing is, for the function that this code snippet exists in, the input string comes in as a string literal parameter. So I would need to find a way to copy the literal into an array, with the added bonus that I am not allowed to use string library functions.

I am open to suggestions on that front.

Comment: @ChasetopherB Iterate over the string to get it's length. Allocate memory `char* modStr = malloc(strLen + 1)`. And copy the string content with `memcpy`.