# c++ overload operator ++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For a school project I have to implement a sensor class in c++ which has a private property active (boolean) which indicates if the sensor is active or not. 
I have to overload the ++ operator in such way that if the operator ++ is used the property active will be set to true.

I implemented the following (sensor.cpp):

```
Sensor::Sensor(int id, std::string vendor) : _id(id), _vendor(vendor) {
    std::cout << "Sensor created with id: " << Sensor::getId() << std::endl;
    _status = false;
}

bool Sensor::getStatus() {
    return _status;
}

void Sensor::setStatus(bool status) {
    _status = status;
}

Sensor& Sensor::operator++() {
    Sensor result = *this;
    this->setStatus(true);
    return result;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Sensor * sensor = new Sensor(1, "sample vendor");
    sensor->setStatus(false);
    sensor++;
    std::cout << "status: " << sensor->getStatus() << std::endl;
}
```

I noticed that the program stops executing (finishes) with the last method to be executed the sensor->setStatus(false); in main.cpp but no error is shown in my terminal nor did my compiler complain.

Does someone has an idea what i did wrong and how I can correct it so that the status is set to true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Quite a few mistakes. Better read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). Also, `++` on a boolean doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `Sensor result = *this;` should be `Sensor &result = *this;` to avoid returning reference to a temporary (better: `return *this;` directly), even if you don't use it. Also you're using an incrementation operator to do something else. Not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sensor` is a pointer, `sensor++` increments the *pointer* not the object.  Easiest solution is to just not use a pointer in the first place.

```
int main() {
    Sensor sensor{1, "sample vendor"};
    sensor.setStatus(false);
    sensor++;
    std::cout << "status: " << sensor.getStatus() << std::endl;
}
```

Another solution is to use `(*sensor)++`...

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Sensor> sensor =
        std::make_unique<Sensor>(1, "sample vendor");
    sensor->setStatus(false);
    (*sensor)++;
    std::cout << "status: " << sensor->getStatus() << std::endl;
}
```

Another error in your code is here:

```
Sensor& Sensor::operator++() {
    // You don't want to do this... it creates a copy!
    Sensor result = *this;
    this->setStatus(true);
    // This is a dangling reference!
    return result;
}
```

Use this instead:

```
Sensor& Sensor::operator++() {
    this->setStatus(true);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: how creative the OPs can be for strange bugs ? :)

Comment: C++ is a great language, it enables people to make creative bugs.

Comment: check that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427771/weird-error-when-reading-a-large-txt-file-in-c/40427819#40427819. Creative as hell.