# Definition of struct in header file

Tags: c

Upon decomposition of my C program I've come across the problem of accessing the structures. Here's the code

> storage.h

```
#ifndef STORAGE_H
#define STORAGE_H

#include "list.h"

#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 1000

typedef struct Finances {
    int revenue;
} Finances;

typedef struct Website
{
    char title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE];
    int visitors;
    float average;
    Finances revenue;

} Website;


List * Strage_readFile(const char * fileName);


#endif
```

> storage.c

```
#include "storage.h"



void blankfunc();
```

> list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include "storage.h"

typedef struct List {
    struct List * next;
} List;

#endif
```

> list.c

```
#include "list.h"


void blankfunc();
```

I'm getting this error

```
storage.h:22:1: error: unknown type name ‘List’
 List * Strage_readFile(const char * fileName);
 ^~~~
```

So, how can I organize the connection between these two headers, so that both Website and List structures were accessible in either headers?

Comment: If it's a C program, do not tag your question C++, nor vice versa.  They're two different languages — you're learning one of them; do not tag with the other (and don't add C# either).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies

Comment: Why do you include `storage.h` in `list.h`?  There's nothing in `list.h` that needs anything from `storage.h`.  Not as shown, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutual inclusion is your problem. `storage.h` must include `list.h` to compile, and `list.h` includes `storage.h` for some reason.

So simply remove the redundant include of `storage.h` from `list.h`

Comment: I down voted as this should have been marked as an exact duplicate. it has been asked many times. And for someone with a reputation like yours, I'd expect it to be marked as duplicate and not answered.

Comment: @TonyTannous: that's not dreadfully constructive.  It is harder to find the duplicates than it is to answer the questions.  By a large margin.  When 'they' provide a good duplicate tracker system that makes it easy for people to find duplicates, your viewpoint may be justified.  Until then, it is very pedantically correct but not dreadfully practically correct.  Also note that the duplicate proffered actually doesn't cover the case of "you don't need to include the header" as a way of breaking dependency cycles.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I figured out very quickly what the problem is, googled for a `circular include` and the first result was the duplicate. Not that hard. For the second part it could have been a comment as well... I can't remove the downvote now unless @StroyTeller edits. But I still don't think this shouldn't have been answered in firstplace.

Comment: @TonyTannous - Not that hard for an experienced developer, or for a person struggling to learn the language? Because if you close as a duplicate, it should damn well be truly "identical" or general enough for the OP to figure out the problem. The one tacked up there is neither.

Comment: @TonyTannous - And you shouldn't be shamed to taking back your downvotes. It's your opinion and it's a legitimate one.

Comment: I have been here long enough to see many questions being closed as duplicates and this case wasn't any different. I am not ashamed, though I regret it, as it was a bit harsh, a comment would have been more appropriate .

Comment: @TonyTannous - Every case is different. Few topics have a true canonical duplicate. If you can suggest one that's really simple to follow, we can use that in the future. Or you could write it yourself. Phrase this question in as general terms as you can, and answer it yourself. Just note that you mean for it to be a canonical dup for people to hammer with (it's quite commonly done these days, actually).

Comment: @TonyTannous - For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults) are what I consider canonical dups to close with.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something but both links were to different question and answers. One regarding the cause of a segmentation fault and the other on the proper way to declare a two dimensional array and the disadvantages of OP example compared to an array residing in a contiguous memory block.

Comment: @TonyTannous - Those were examples of what a canonical duplicate *should* look like... not canonical dups to *this* question...