# following code is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute following code which is giving me segmentation fault. What error I am doing or am I missing any part ? can this code be implemented in some other way?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

struct A {
    char* a;
};

int main()
{
    struct A *x;
    x->a = "soumya";
    char* str = "soumya";
    cout<<str<<endl<<(char*)x->a<<endl;
   // if(strcmp(x->a,str)!=0)
  //  {
   //     cout<<"not same"<<endl;
   // }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not a c++ guru but if I had to guess it looks like you're attempting to utilize a variable before initializing it (and I'm not sure that'd be the correct usage of the `struct` keyword inside of the code body)

Comment: `struct A *x;` //uninitialized wild pointer

`x->a = "soumya";` //invitation to disaster; accesses the address out of process space and ends up with segmentation fault issued by the OS

`A *x = new A` and also delete it later using `delete A` to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: @soumya You can, and should, accept an answer it it provide you with the required guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not initializing the `x` pointer to `struct A` so initially it points to some undefined area in memory which is not allocated.

So by doing `x->a = "soumya";` you are trying to write this space which causes segmentation fault.

You can change

```
struct A *x;
```

to

```
struct A *x = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
// Don't forget to free this memory if your program is going to run for some time
```

or to

```
struct A x;
```

And replace every `x->a` with `x.a` in this case memory is allocated in stack so it will automatically be freed at the end of the method.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues we need to cover.

1) do not use raw pointers in C++ anymore, in general.

2) you do not actually allocate any memory for `*x`. This can be achieved by doing:

```
struct A *x = new A;
```

Remember to call `delete x`, to deallocate the memory when appropriate.

The third problem is that you do not allocate memory for the content of `x->a`. The best solution is to use `std::string` instead of a char pointer. 
Then you are allowed to do `x->a = "soumya";`.

You struct should then be

```
struct A {
    std::string a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version :

Use of `const char *` because you assign constant string

Use of `struct A x;` to have the `struct` allocated and not only a pointer to a non allocated memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"
using namespace std;
struct A {
    const char* a;
};
int main()
{
    struct A x;
    x.a = "soumya";
    const char* str = "soumya";
    cout<<str<<endl<<x.a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```