# passing a char* as argument breaks program whereas char[] does not

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have the following code to split strings by tokens:

```
char **strToWordArray(char *str, const char *delimiter)
{
  char **words;
  int nwords = 1;
  words = malloc(sizeof(*words) * (nwords + 1));

  int w = 0;
  int len = strlen(delimiter);
  words[w++] = str;
  while (*str)
  {
    if (strncmp(str, delimiter, len) == 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      {
        *(str++) = 0;
      }
      if (*str != 0) {
        nwords++;
        char **tmp = realloc(words, sizeof(*words) * (nwords + 1));
        words = tmp;
        words[w++] = str;
      } else {
          str--;
      }
    }
    str++;
  }
  words[w] = NULL;
  return words;
}
```

If I do this:

```
char str[] = "abc/def/foo/bar";
char **words=strToWordArray(str,"/");
```

then the program works just fine but if I do this:

```
char *str = "abc/def/foo/bar";
char **words=strToWordArray(str,"/");
```

then I get a segmentation fault.

Why is that? The program expects a `char*` as an argument then why does a `char*` argument crash the program?

Comment: TL;DR: Your modifying `str`, but when you do `char* str = ""` you can't modify that data because what you have is a pointer to memory you aren't allowed to touch. `char[] str = ""` is a copy you can do whatever you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function contains:

```
    *(str++) = 0;
```

which modifies the string that was passed to it. When you do:

```
char *str = "abc/def/foo/bar";
```

`str` points to a read-only string literal. See the section titled **Attempting to modify a string literal** in this question:

[Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: That makes sense now. Is it possible to make the char pointer writable?

Comment: Make it point to an array instead of a literal. `char str[] = "xxx"; char *str1 = str;`

Comment: BTW, isn't your function the same as `strtok()`?

Comment: Nope, strtok considers consecutive delimiters as one whereas this program does not. For ex. for abc//def, strtok will give abc and def whereas this program will give abc and /def