# Why does this C program which dereferences an aliased area of memory cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *myptr = calloc(500,1);
    char *myptr2 = myptr;

    *myptr++ = 'A';
    *myptr++ = 'B';
    *myptr = '\0';
    /* This should dereference the beginning of the memory and print until myptr[2] which is '\0' */
    printf("Myptr2 points to: %s\n", *myptr2);

    free(myptr);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Why is line 13 (the printf line) creating a SIGSEV? It should be pointing to the beginning of the memory and then printf should print until it hits the '\0'.

Comment: Very common mistake: you should _not_ dereference `myptr2` in the call to `printf`.

Comment: Change `%s` to `%c` in your  `printf`

Comment: @the_endian  The pointer myptr was changed. So write  free(myptr2);

Comment: @zwol can you tell conceptually what the problem is? If you dereference a pointer to the memory, what does this cause?

Comment: Terrible newbie mistake to increment a pointer and then try to `free` it.

Comment: Your compiler should warn about an invalid type. **Always** enable all recommended warnings and treat them as errors!

Comment: I feel like this _has_ to be a duplicate, but I'm not having any luck finding something to dupehammer it to. The "[definitive list of common reasons for segmentation faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)" doesn't cover this case, but arguably should (and then again arguably _shouldn't_, since it's a C++ question so the commentariat will insist you ought to use iostreams instead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can you tell conceptually what the problem is? If you dereference a pointer to the memory, what does this cause?

When you have a `%s` slot in the format string, `printf` expects to see a `char*` as the corresponding argument. That's why you should pass `myptr2` (which is *the address* of `'A'` and from which the subsequent addresses of the string characters can be deduced).

If you pass `*myptr2` instead, you are basically passing the character `'A'` itself (with no information whatsoever as to where that particular `'A'` is — which would have allowed `printf` to read the rest of the string). Simply put, `printf` expected a pointer there, so it attempts to treat the corresponding argument as a pointer.

Now notice that the character you passed (by dereferencing a `char*`, therefore getting a `char` with the value of `'A'`) has a size of 1 byte, while a pointer has a size of 4 or 8 bytes typically. This means that `printf` will most likely read a garbage address made up of a character and some random data found in the stack. There can be no guarantees as to what can happen to the program in this case, so the whole incident invokes *undefined behavior.*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the thorough and appropriate answer!

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you should not dereference myptr2 in second argument of printf, so you have to replace:

```
printf("Myptr2 points to: %s\n", *myptr2);
```

with:

```
printf("Myptr2 points to: %s\n", myptr2);
```

When using %s with printf, you have to give the pointer on first character of the string.