# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. C++ LIST

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

**L.insert()** gives segmentation fault if I call it after **L.deleteElement()**.
This is the error message:

```
196     nPtr = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));
(gdb) print(c)
$7 = 2
(gdb) next
197     if(nPtr!=NULL){
(gdb) print(nPtr)
$8 = (nodePtr) 0x615c70
(gdb) next
198         nPtr->data = element;
(gdb) print(element)
$9 = "("
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b74413 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I created a new node and didn't dereference any uninitialized pointer! Can anyone explain why I get this error? And it works as expected until I call it after L.deleteEle().

Here is my full prog:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    string data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
class List
{
    nodePtr head;
    int count;
    nodePtr tail;
public:
    List(nodePtr h=NULL,int c=0,nodePtr t=NULL){ // constructor
        head=h;
        count=c;
        tail=t;
    } 
    bool insert(string element, int position=1); // if position is invalid, returns false ; takes default position as START (1)
    bool deleteEle(int position); // deletes the node at specified position, else returns false.
};

bool List::deleteEle(int position)
{
    if(position>count){
        return false;
    }
    nodePtr pPtr;
    nodePtr cPtr;
    nodePtr tPtr;
    int p=position;
    if(position==1){
        cPtr=head;
        tPtr=cPtr->next;
        head=tPtr;
        free(cPtr);
        count-=1;
        return true;
    }
    cPtr=head;
    pPtr=NULL;
    while(p>1){
        pPtr=cPtr;
        cPtr=cPtr->next;
        p--;
    }
    if(position==count){
        tail=pPtr;
        tail->next=NULL;
        free(cPtr);
        count-=1;
        return true;
    }
    tPtr=cPtr->next;
    pPtr->next=tPtr;
    free(cPtr);
    count-=1;
    return true;
}
bool List::insert(string element, int position)
{
    if (position>count+1){
        return false;
    }
    int c = position;
    nodePtr nPtr;
    nodePtr tPtr;
    nodePtr cPtr;
    nPtr = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(nPtr!=NULL){
        nPtr->data = element;
        nPtr->next = NULL;

        tPtr = NULL;
        cPtr = head;
        if(cPtr==NULL){
            head=nPtr;
            tail=nPtr;
            count+=1;
            return true;
        }
        else if(position==count+1){
            cout<<"ikkade !!!";
            tail->next=nPtr;
            tail=nPtr;
            count+=1;
            return true;
        }
        else if(position==1){
            head=nPtr;
            nPtr->next=cPtr;
            count+=1;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            while(cPtr!=NULL && c>2){
                cPtr = cPtr->next;
                c--; 
            }
            tPtr=cPtr->next;
            cPtr->next=nPtr;
            nPtr->next=tPtr;
            count+=1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<element<<" not inserted! No memory available.";
        return false;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    List L;
    L.insert("(",L.size()+1);
    L.insert("+",L.size()+1);
    L.deleteEle(L.size());
    L.insert("(",L.size()+1); //fails here
return 0;       
}
```

Insert fails after calling deleteEle!

Comment: What are you using C-style malloc/free memory allocation in what purports to be a C++ program ?

Comment: Another C++ student sacrificed to the linked list gods.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show the code if insert and the class definiton? Your debugger trace does not even look like it is running through the function you posted.

Comment: Do not use `malloc` and `free`.  If `nodePtr` points to something that is not C-layout compatible (a POD type), those calls to `malloc` invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Aha, like I said, using `malloc` is a non-starter.  Your `node` class contains a `std::string`.  Where did you get the idea to use `malloc`?  Even very bad C++ books won't have the student using `malloc`.  Was this your idea?

Comment: I just pasted this in [ideone](https://ideone.com/vOWS3x), added the size function and replaced malloc/free with new/delete and it does not crash. I think @PaulMcKenzie should make an answer of his comment ;)

Comment: See also, [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047453/472647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that can cause a segmentation fault is the (mis)use of `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program to create objects dynamically.

This struct:

```
struct node
{
    string data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

and then later code doing this:

`nPtr = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));`

does not create `node` objects, since the constructor for `node` is not invoked, thus the default constructor for `std::string` is not invoked.

All the `malloc` does is allocate `sizeof(node)` bytes -- no `node` object is actually created.  You are now left with a bunch of allocated bytes just laying around that do not form any sort of `node` object whatsoever.  Any use of `nPtr` as if it is a valid object invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of `malloc` and `free`, use `new` and `delete`, since `new` calls the constructor for the object, while `malloc` doesn't, and in addtion, `delete` calls the destructor while `free` does not.

So replace the `malloc` and `free` calls you're making now with the following (of course, change the names of the variables where necessary):

`nPtr = new node;`

and then when done:

`delete nPtr;`

---

Now `malloc` has its uses when creating an object -- it can be used for things such as [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new), where you would issue a call to `malloc`, and then use that to create the object.  But obviously your code is not using `placement-new`.