# Tricky Segmentation faults with BST recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add strings to a Binary Search Tree using a recursive insert method (the usual for BSTs, IIRC) so I can later print them out using recursion as well.

Trouble is, I've been getting a segmentation faults I don't really understand. Related code follows (this block of code is from my main function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Stores the size of the C-strings we will use;
// Standardized to 100 (assignment specifications say
// ALL strings will be no more than 100 characters long)

// Please note that I defined this as a preprocessor
// directive because using the const keyword makes it
// impossible to define the size of the C-String array
// (C doesn't allow for static array struct members whose
// size is given as a variable)

#define STRING_SIZE 100

// The flags for case sensitivity
// and an output file

int cflag = 0, oflag = 0;

// These are intended to represent the boolean
// values true and false (there's no native bool
// data type in C, apparently)

const int TRUE = 1;
const int FALSE = 0;

// Type alias for the bool type

typedef int bool;

// This is the BST struct. A BST is basically just
// a Node with at most two children (left and right)
// and a data element.

typedef struct BST
{
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
    char *key;
    int counter;
} BST;

// ----- FUNCTION PROTOTYPES -----


void insert(BST **root, char *key);

int caseSenStrCmp(char *str1, char *str2);

int caseInsenStrCmp(char *str1, char *str2);

bool existsInTree(BST *root, char *key, int cflag);

void inOrderPrint(BST *root, int oflag, FILE *outFile);

void deallocateTree(BST *root);



int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    extern char *optarg;
    extern int optind;
    int c, err = 0;

    // Holds the current line in the file/user-provided string.

    char currentLine[STRING_SIZE];

    // This will store the input/output file
    // directories

    char fileDirectory[STRING_SIZE];

    static char usage[] = "Usage: %s [-c] [-o output_file_name] [input_file_name]\n";

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "co:")) != -1)
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'c':
                cflag = 1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                oflag = 1;

                // If an output file name
                // was entered, copy it
                // to fileDirectory

                if (argv[optind] != NULL)
                {
                    strcpy(fileDirectory, argv[optind]);
                }

                break;
            case '?':
                err = 1;
                break;
            default:
                err = 1;
                break;
        }

    if (err)
    {
        // Generic error message

        printf("ERROR: Invalid input.\n");

        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // --- BST SORT CODE STARTS HERE ---

    printf("This is BEFORE setting root to NULL\n");

    // This is the BST. As the assignment instructions
    // specify, it is initially set to NULL

    BST *root = NULL;

    // Pointer to the mode the files
    // will be opened in. Starts as
    // "w" since we're opening the output file
    // first

    printf("This is AFTER setting root to NULL\n");

    char *mode = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    strcpy(mode, "w");

    printf("Wrote w to mode pointer");

    // Pointer to the output file

    FILE *outFile;

    // Attempt to open output file

    outFile = fopen(fileDirectory, mode);

    printf("Opened outfile \n");

    // Now update mode and fileDirectory so
    // we can open the INPUT file

    strcpy(mode, "r");

    printf("Wrote r to mode\n");

    // Check if we have an input file name
    // If argv[optind] isn't NULL, that means we have
    // an input file name, so copy it into fileDirectory

    if (argv[optind] != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(fileDirectory, argv[optind]);
    }


    printf("Wrote input file name to fileDirectory.\n");

    // Pointer to the input file

    FILE *inFile;

    // Attempt to open the input file

    //printf("%d", inFile = fopen(fileDirectory, mode));

    printf("Opened input file\n");

    // If the input file was opened successfully, process it

    if (inFile != NULL)
    {
        // Process the file while EOF isn't
        // returned

        while (!feof(inFile))
        {
            // Get a single line (one string)

            //fgets(currentLine, STRING_SIZE, inFile);

            printf("Wrote to currentLine; it now contains: %s\n", currentLine);

            // Check whether the line is an empty line

            if (*currentLine != '\n')
            {
                // If the string isn't an empty line, call
                // the insert function

                printf("currentLine wasn't the NULL CHAR");

                insert(&root, currentLine);
            }
        }

        // At this point, we're done processing
        // the input file, so close it

        fclose(inFile);

    }

        // Otherwise, process user input from standard input

    else
    {

        do
        {

            printf("Please enter a string (or blank line to exit): ");

            // Scanf takes user's input from stdin. Note the use
            // of the regex [^\n], allowing the scanf statement
            // to read input until the newline character is encountered
            // (which happens when the user is done writing their string
            // and presses the Enter key)

            scanf("%[^\n]s", currentLine);

            // Call the insert function on the line
            // provided

            insert(&root, currentLine);
        } while (caseSenStrCmp(currentLine, "") != 0);

    }

    // At this point, we've read all the input, so
    // perform in-order traversal and print all the
    // strings as per assignment specification

    inOrderPrint(root, oflag, outFile);

    // We're done, so reclaim the tree

    deallocateTree(root);

}

// ===== AUXILIARY METHODS ======

// Creates a new branch for the BST and returns a
// pointer to it. Will be called by the insert()
// function. Intended to keep the main() function
// as clutter-free as possible.

BST* createBranch(char *keyVal)
{
    // Create the new branch to be inserted into
    // the tree

    BST* newBranch = (BST*)malloc(sizeof(BST));

    // Allocate memory for newBranch's C-string

    newBranch->key = (char*)malloc(STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    // Copy the user-provided string into newBranch's
    // key field

    strcpy(newBranch->key, keyVal);

    // Set newBranch's counter value to 1. This
    // will be incremented if/when other instances
    // of the key are inserted into the tree

    newBranch->counter = 1;

    // Set newBranch's child branches to null

    newBranch->left = NULL;
    newBranch->right = NULL;

    // Return the newly created branch

    return newBranch;
}


// Adds items to the BST. Includes functionality
// to verify whether an item already exists in the tree

// Note that we pass the tree's root to the insert function
// as a POINTER TO A POINTER so that changes made to it
// affect the actual memory location that was passed in
// rather than just the local pointer

void insert(BST **root, char *key)
{

    printf("We made it to the insert function!");
    // Check if the current branch is empty

    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        // If it is, create a new
        // branch here and insert it

        // This will also initialize the
        // entire tree when the first element
        // is inserted (i.e. when the tree is
        // empty)

        *root = createBranch(key);
    }

    // If the tree ISN'T empty, check whether
    // the element we're trying to insert
    // into the tree is already in it

    // If it is, don't insert anything (the
    // existsInTree function takes care of
    // incrementing the counter associated
    // with the provided string)

    if (!existsInTree(*root, key, cflag))
    {
        // If it isn't, check if the case sensitivity
        // flag is set; if it is, perform the
        // checks using case-sensitive string
        // comparison function

        if (cflag) {
            // Is the string provided (key) is
            // greater than the string stored
            // at the current branch?

            if (caseSenStrCmp((*root)->key, key))
            {
                // If so, recursively call the
                // insert() function on root's
                // right child (that is, insert into
                // the right side of the tree)

                // Note that we pass the ADDRESS
                // of root's right branch, since
                // the insert function takes a
                // pointer to a pointer to a BST
                // as an argument

                insert(&((*root)->right), key);
            }

                // If not, the key passed in is either less than
                // or equal to the current branch's key,
                // so recursively call the insert()
                // function on root's LEFT child (that is,
                // insert into the left side of the tree)

            else
            {
                insert(&((*root)->left), key);
            }
        }

            // If it isn't, perform the checks using
            // the case-INsensitive string comparison
            // function

        else {
            // The logic here is exactly the same
            // as the comparisons above, except
            // it uses the case-insensitive comparison
            // function

            if (caseInsenStrCmp((*root)->key, key))
            {
                insert(&((*root)->right), key);
            }
            else
            {
                insert(&((*root)->left), key);
            }
        }
    }
}


// CASE SENSITIVE STRING COMPARISON function. Returns:
// -1 if str1 is lexicographically less than str2
// 0 if str1 is lexicographically equal to str2
// 1 if str2 is lexicographically greater than str1
```

I'm using getopt to parse options that the user enters. I've been doing a little bit of basic debugging using printf statements just to see how far I get into the code before it crashes, and I've more or less narrowed down the cause. It seems to be this part here:

```
do
{

    printf("Please enter a string (or blank line to exit): ");

    // Scanf takes user's input from stdin. Note the use
    // of the regex [^\n], allowing the scanf statement
    // to read input until the newline character is encountered
    // (which happens when the user is done writing their string
    // and presses the Enter key)

    scanf("%[^\n]s", currentLine);

    // Call the insert function on the line
    // provided

    insert(&root, currentLine);

} while (caseSenStrCmp(currentLine, "\n") != 0);
```

Or rather, calls to the insert function in general, since the printf statement I put at the beginning of the insert function ("We made it to the insert function!) gets printed over and over again until the program finally crashes with a segmentation fault, which probably means the problem is infinite recursion?

If so, I don't understand why it's happening. I initialized the root node to NULL at the beginning of main, so it should go directly into the insert functions *root == NULL case, at least on its first call.

Does it maybe have something to do with the way I pass root as a pointer to a pointer (BST **root in parameter list of insert function)? Am I improperly recursing, i.e. is this statement (and others similar to it)

```
 insert(&((*root)->right), key);
```

incorrect somehow? This was my first guess, but I don't see how that would cause infinite recursion - if anything, it should fail without recursing at all if that was the case? Either way, it doesn't explain why infinite recursion happens when root is NULL (i.e. on the first call to insert, wherein I pass in &root - a pointer to the root pointer - to the insert function).

I'm really stuck on this one. At first I thought it might have something to do with the way I was copying strings to currentLine, since the line

```
if(*currentLine != '\0')
```

in the while (!feof(inFile)) loop also crashes the program with a segmentation fault, but even when I commented that whole part out just to test the rest of the code I ended up with the infinite recursion problem.

Any help at all is appreciated here, I've been trying to fix this for over 5 hours to no avail. I legitimately don't know what to do.

**EDIT: Since a lot of the comments involved questions regarding the way I declared other variables and such in the rest of the code, I've decided to include the entirety of my code, at least until the insert() function, which is where the problem (presumably) is. I only omitted things to try and keep the code to a minimum - I'm sure nobody likes to read through large blocks of code.

Barmar:

Regarding fopen() and fgets(): these were commented out so that inFile would remain NULL and the relevant conditional check would fail, since that part of the code also fails with a segmentation fault

createBranch() does initialize both the left and right children of the node it creates to NULL (as can be seen above)

currentLine is declared as an array with a static size.

@coderredoc:

My understanding of it is that it reads from standard input until it encounters the newline character (i.e. user hits the enter button), which isn't recorded as part of the string

I can already see where you were going with this! My loop conditional was set for the do/while loop was set to check for the newline character, so the loop would never have terminated. That's absolutely my fault; it was a carryover from a previous implementation of that block that I forgot to change.

I did change it after you pointed it out (see new code above), but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem (I'm guessing it's because of the infinite recursion happening inside the insert() function - once it gets called the first time, it never returns and just crashes with a segfault).
**

Comment: [Why `while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: You have `fopen` and `fgets()` commented out. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: The line returned by `fgets()` includes the newline. So on an empty line, `*currentline == '\n'`

Comment: Does `createBranch()` initialize `left` and `right` to `NULL`?

Comment: If you've been working in a debugger, it should tell you exactly which line the segfault is happening on, and you should be able to examine the value of the variable that's causing it.

Comment: How do you declare `currentLine`? Is it a pointer or an array? If it's a pointer, have you allocated memory for it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s" ...` Do you understand this ?

Comment: All comments addressed and checking out the links provided by Barmar now. Thanks very much for the swift response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out - turns out the problem was with the insert() function after all. I rewrote it (and the rest of the code that was relevant) to use a regular pointer rather than a pointer to a pointer:

```
BST* insert(BST* root, char *key)
{

// If branch is null, call createBranch
// to make one, then return it

if (root == NULL)
{
    return createBranch(key);
}

// Otherwise, check whether the key
// already exists in the tree

if (!existsInTree(root, key, cflag))
{
    // If it doesn't, check whether
    // the case sensitivity flag is set

    if (cflag)
    {

        // If it is, use the case-sensitive
        // string comparison function to
        // decide where to insert the key

        if (caseSenStrCmp(root->key, key))
        {
            // If the key provided is greater
            // than the string stored at the
            // current branch, insert into
            // right child

            root->right = insert(root->right, key);
        }

        else
        {
            // Otherwise, insert into left child

            root->left = insert(root->left, key);
        }
    }

    // If it isn't, use the case-INsensitive string
    // comparison function to decide where to insert

    else
    {

        // Same logic as before. If the key
        // provided is greater, insert into
        // current branch's right child

        if (caseInsenStrCmp(root->key, key))
        {
            root->right = insert(root->right, key);
        }

        // Otherwise, insert into the left child

        else
        {
            root->left = insert(root ->left, key);
        }
    }
}

// Return the root pointer

return root;
}
```

Which immediately solved the infinite recursion/seg fault issue. It did reveal a few other minor semantic errors (most of which were probably made in frustration as I desperately tried to fix this problem without rewriting the insert function), but I've been taking care of those bit by bit.

I've now got a new problem (albeit probably a simpler one than this) which I'll make a separate thread for, since it's not related to segmentation faults.

Comment: Your current version of `insert` sort of works, but so does your original version. There is a considerable number of serious problems with your code, but `insert` is not one of those.