# How to print a char array in C through printf?

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

This results in segmentation fault.
What needs to be corrected?

```
int main(void)
{
    char a_static = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'};
    char b_static = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f'};

    printf("\n value of a_static: %s", a_static);
    printf("\n value of b_static: %s\n", b_static);
}
```

Comment: `char *a_static` use a pointer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33047452/758133

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The code posted is incorrect: `a_static` and `b_static` should be defined as arrays.

There are two ways to correct the code:

- you can add null terminators to make these arrays proper C strings:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) {
      char a_static[] = { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', '\0' };
      char b_static[] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', '\0' };

      printf("value of a_static: %s\n", a_static);
      printf("value of b_static: %s\n", b_static);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Alternately, `printf` can print the contents of an array that is not null terminated using the precision field:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) {
      char a_static[] = { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r' };
      char b_static[] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };

      printf("value of a_static: %.4s\n", a_static);
      printf("value of b_static: %.*s\n", (int)sizeof(b_static), b_static);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  The precision given after the `.` specifies the maximum number of characters to output from the string. It can be given as a decimal number or as `*` and provided as an `int` argument before the `char` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

*This results in segmentation fault. ?* because of the below statement

```
char a_static = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'};
```

`a_static` should be `char array` to hold multiple characters. make it like

```
 char a_static[] = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r','\0'}; /* add null terminator at end of array */
```

Similarly for `b_static`

```
char b_static[] = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f','\0'};
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the fault.

Comment: You should also add the '\0' characters in your char array to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use array instead of declaring

```
a_static
b_static
```

as variables

So it look like this:

```
int main()
{
  char a_static[] = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r','\0'};
  char b_static[] = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f','\0'};
  printf("a_static=%s,b_static=%s",a_static,b_static);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are using C Style Strings, and a C Style String is terminated by a zero.
For example if you'd want to print "alien" by using a char array:

```
char mystring[6] = { 'a' , 'l', 'i', 'e' , 'n', 0}; //see the last zero? That is what you are missing (that's why C Style String are also named null terminated strings, because they need that zero)
printf("mystring is \"%s\"",mystring);
```

The output should be:

> mystring is "alien"

Back to your code, it should look like:

```
int main(void) 
{
  char a_static[5] = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 0};
  char b_static[5] = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 0}; 
  printf("\n value of a_static: %s", a_static); 
  printf("\n value of b_static: %s\n", b_static); 
  return 0;//return 0 means the program executed correctly
}
```

By the way, instead of arrays you can use pointers (if you don't need to modify the string):

```
char *string = "my string"; //note: "my string" is a string literal
```

Also you can initialize your char arrays with string literals too:

```
char mystring[6] = "alien"; //the zero is put by the compiler at the end
```

Also: Functions that operate on C Style Strings (e.g. printf, sscanf, strcmp,, strcpy, etc) need zero to know where the string ends

Hope that you learned something from this answer.

Comment: That's problematic and partially wrong in various places. For a start: pointers are **never** a replacement for arrays. If one feels like answering questions witrh broken code and lack of fundamentals like that, they at least should get it very correct so OP will not need to buy a textbook to learn the language properly which would be the correct way.