# OpenCL: attempting to print sizeof(cl_int *) gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm pretty new to OpenCL and wanted to check sizes of its different datatypes but attempting to print sizeof cl_int* gives segmentation fault. I can not find a logical reason for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>
void main(){
cl_int a;
printf("size:%d\n",sizeof(size_t));
cl_int num = 10;
printf(sizeof(cl_int *));
exit(0);
//cl_int *data,*data_2,*data_3 = (cl_int *)malloc(num*sizeof(cl_int));
printf("Done!");
}
```

Comment: `printf` expects a format string as first parameter.

Comment: Does the code as shown compile warning free, even if you use strict warnings?

Comment: Please explain what you intend to achieve with this line and additionally  how you understand the syntax. `printf("%d",sizeof(cl_int *));`.

Comment: Thanks now it is works fine. It would be great if you could tell me more about why this error occurred.

Comment: I was basically trying to find sizes of different OpenCL datatypes and had also put cl_int * just for curiosity but got stuck. I had used printf with sizeof() before too but had never encountered errors. Will keep this in mind for future.

Comment: Please don't edit code in questiions to as to invalidate comments/answers.  It's very confusing for future visitors/users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Answer (score -1):

You seems forgot about format of printf
try something like this:

```
cl_int num = 10;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
printf("[%d]\n",sizeof(cl_int));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
printf("[%d]\n",sizeof(num));
```

Comment: This is still undefined behaviour, wrong format specifier

Comment: its long int vs int. while number is below 10