# Debugging a Segmentation fault with unknown input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am doing a C course, i am recoding some basic functions, and a program is correcting me and returning "Segmentation fault (Signal -11)", but i have no stack trace, i have spent hours trying to debug this. Do you have any idea what input could cause a segfault with my functions.

[link to my lib](https://gist.github.com/simondutertre/dbb5b3cef298b6ef12d99e3cb07d14f4)

Comment: Post your code here as a [mcve], not a link to an external site.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults