# My code is giving me a segmentation error in loop how do i fix that

Tags: arrays, c

The task is to remove all the duplicates in array but i am encountering this error this is my first time in c and i don't know how to debug this

```
#include<stdio.h>

void remove_duplicates(int arr[],int *size1,int index)
{
    for(int j = index; j<*size1-1;j++)
    {
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
    }
    (*size1)--;
}
void find_duplicates(int arr[],int * size1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<*size1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1;j<*size1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            remove_duplicates(arr,*size1,j);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,3,4,5,4,3,2,5,2};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int *size1 = &size;
    find_duplicates(arr,size1);
    for(int i = 0; i<*size1; i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted it to run perfectly

Comment: You need a debugger to step through your program one line at the time and inspect your variables. Many IDE's include them, but there are also good ones online like [this](https://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit).

Comment: `find_duplicates` is calling `remove_duplicates` with the incorrect parameter value `*size1`. It should be `size1`. The compiler should have given you a warning about calling the function with incompatible parameters.

Comment: The error indicated by @IanAbbott must have been signaled by the compiler

Comment: Please pay attention to compiler warnings. GCC, Clang, and MSVC all give warnings at default settings (and newer versions of Clang give errors).

Comment: The code has an efficiency of O(n^3). It should be possible to get that down to O(n^2).

Comment: I am not bothered about complexity it is just an assignment

Comment: Useful reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)

Comment: Thanks guys, though i was not able to solve my problem because i could not understand it i am keeping this error for some other day and come back at it when i get more experienced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to debug depends heavy on the compiler environment and maybe the IDE you use on top of it. Generally speaking:

1. Compile with debug flag/options on
2. run program in debugger
3. check on which line the program crashes and error code

For the example use a linux (-like) command line using gcc & gdb :

1. gcc -g ravistuff.c -o ravistuff
   (you already get a good warning here...but say you ignore it)
2. gdb ravistuff
   ...gdb startup text..
   (gdb)run
3. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0x00005555555551bd in remove_duplicates (arr=0x7fffffffe060, size1=0x9, index=5) at ravistuff.c:5
   5           for(int j = index; j<*size1-1;j++)

This will get you a few clues:

- you get a SIGSEGV, in general that means you are poking in memory that isn't yours
- size1=0x9 => *size=*value of address 0x9* => shouldn't be right

Conclusion:
*size1* should be an adress to an int, not an int itselves;
as one poster correctly stated, you called "remove_duplicates" in "find_duplicates" with an *size1 , but size1 in this function already comes in as *size1, so you get **size1 ....

Welcome to C.You are messing hard with pointers, try to avoid complex operations with pointers as much as possible, especially as a beginner. Its saver to just declare a second array instead of messing arround with pointers in an existing array. However, if you still insist on having the end result in the same array, the code can still be written in much simpler, efficient,easier (and safer) way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,3,4,5,4,3,2,5,2};
    int newsize=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    for (int x=0;x<newsize-1;x++)
    {
        for (int y=x+1;y<newsize;y++)
        {
            if (arr[x]==arr[y])
            {
                newsize--;
                for (int shift=y--;shift<newsize;shift++)
                    arr[shift]=arr[shift+1];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<newsize;i++)
        printf("%d%c",arr[i],i<newsize-1?',':'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will go through this when i gain some knowledge i am  a python person and i am used to dynamic allocations here i am stuck because i am direction less